# Deploy only build react app to app engine

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I managed to deploy correctly a react app to google app engine.

The build folder is correctly served from app engine, but the deployment contains also all the other files.

How can I deploy only the build folder?

Answer (score 2):

You can add all the files and folder you do not want to deploy to the .gcloudignore file. It's very similar to .gitignore for git.
More on .gcloudignore here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore